# Разница между выполнением в python.exe и IDLE (pythonw.exe)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

Когда выполняю строку `print(os.environ)` в python.exe вижу одно.
В IDLE (pythonw.exe) вижу другое.

Что такое может быть? Какие-то кэши у IDLE сохраняют старую версию `PATH` или что?

Система Windows 7 x64, Python x32.

Вот результат с *python.exe*:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\Driver;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;
C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;
C:\Users\someusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\;
C:\Users\someusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;
C:\Users\someusername\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Вот результат с *pythonw.exe*:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\Driver;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;
C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
C:\Users\someusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\;
C:\Users\someusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\
```

Конкретная проблема в том что *nodejs* нет в *PATH* в случае с *pythonw.exe*, поэтому модуль *pyexecjs*, который нужен мне не работает в *pythonw.exe* (хотя в *python.exe* работает, но там и *nodejs* в *path* имеется)

Comment: А нам можно посмотреть?

Comment: @titov_andrei Перенёс уточнение из ответа

Comment: Как запускаем `python` и как запускаем `pythonw`? Как `nodejs` добавлялся в `PATH`?